# Can't understand MYSQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to put some data into my MySQL db via phpmyadmin.

I'm getting a syntax error near '' in line 1. '' Is not existing at all...

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

SQL Command:

```
INSERT INTO GAR (`Name`,`Latitude`,`Longitude`,`Adresse`,`PLZ`,`Ort`,`Land`,`Tel`,`www`,`Email`,`Bericht`)
  VALUES (
    'Wellnesshotel Seeschl��chen�****�Hotel & Freizeitpark GmbH Buchwalde',
    'empty',
    'empty',
    'Buchwaldstr. 77',
    '1968',
    'Senftenberg',
    'D',
    '03573 37890',
    'www.lausitztherme.de',
    'm.zander@lausitztherme.de',
    '03573 378932');
```

Comment: try inserting manually by executing your sql statment . if you are using a workbench it would probably give you the place where you get an error.

Comment: If that's a real email / business they might appreciate you obfuscating it a bit

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the strange characters in your value for "name". I wouldn't be surprised if that gets MySQL confused,

Comment: Grave accents in the field names and data values?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Latitude` and `Longitude` are of numeric type such as `Float` or `Double`, that `'empty'` you are trying to insert could be the issue.

If this is the case, try:

```
INSERT INTO GAR (`Name`,`Latitude`,`Longitude`,`Adresse`,`PLZ`,`Ort`,`Land`,`Tel`,`www`,`Email`,`Bericht`)
  VALUES (
    'Wellnesshotel Seeschl��chen�****�Hotel & Freizeitpark GmbH Buchwalde',
    0,
    0,
    'Buchwaldstr. 77',
    '1968',
    'Senftenberg',
    'D',
    '03573 37890',
    'www.lausitztherme.de',
    'm.zander@lausitztherme.de',
    '03573 378932');
```

If this is not the issue, it would help if you include the schema for the `GAR` table.